# Python loadtxt function is not working

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

I am attempting the following program.

```
from numpy import zeros,loadtxt
from pylab import plot,xlim,show
from cmath import exp,pi

def dft(y):
    N = len(y)
    c = zeros(N//2+1,complex)
    for k in range(N//2+1):
        for n in range(N):
            c[k] += y[n]*exp(-2j*pi*k*n/N)
    return c

y = loadtxt("pitch.txt",float)
c = dft(y)
plot(abs(c))
xlim(0,500)
show()
```

However, when I attempt to run the program, I receive an error code for the line 13:

```
 y = loadtxt("pitch.txt",float)
  File "C:\Python32\lib\site-packages\numpy\lib\npyio.py", line 689, in loadtxt
    fh = iter(open(fname, 'U'))
IOError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'pitch.txt'
```

I was given a file that has all the resources needed to run the program, and I uploaded them into the same folders I have my Python program saved in. The pitch.txt file is a text file with a single column of numbers. I'm wondering if there is something wrong with the written program, or do did I upload the files in the wrong.

Comment: Are you 100% sure the file is there and has _exactly_ this name? Windows has this annoying setting of hiding file extensions. Maybe the true name of the file is `pitch.txt.txt`?

Comment: Try `import os; os.getcwd(); os.walk('.')` to get your current working directory and a list of all the files therein the way Python sees them.

Comment: THANK YOU, the second comment helped a lot

Comment: So, just out of curiosity, what was it?

Comment: Honestly, very embarrassing. It was just an issue with the way I've been saving the program files on my computer. The locations of everything was all messed up.